# QNAP rsync delate files on server

Tags: rsync, qnap

I have approx. 20k photos on my PC, divided into several subdir. I use RSYNC to backup it to QNAP NAS with RSYNC server running on it (taken from Entware-NG). 
My command running on PC to RSYNC photos from PC to QNAP looks like this:

```
rsync --delete --password-file /home/maciek/Pobrane/pass-1 -vratx --max-size=2.99G --exclude-from=/home/maciek/Pobrane/pomin.txt --delete-after --force --one-file-system --safe-links --progress /home/maciek/Obrazy/ media@media::Zdjecia
```

It work nice but there is one problem. QNAP creates by itself thumbnail images and place it into subdir named `.@__thumb` in each photo dir.
After running command above, all `.@__thumb` subdirs and its content are removed from server. So after that QNAP rebuild it again. It is noisy and long process.
My question is. How to modify the command above, so that the directories `.@__thumb` were not removed ?

Answer (score 1):

DONE. It is necessary to add in command option:

```
--filter='-p .@__thumb'
```

Thats all